# Underpaid Invoice

Tags: transactions

I happened to pay a little less bitcoins than needed for my transaction (i didnt counted the currency difference) and the merchant said it was possible to either send me less of what i am buying or he can refund my transaction. Since then I received no answer and now i am waiting more than 24h for response. I have all the detail needed, I just want either what i bought or a refund. What is you opinion ? What should I do ? I received nothing , my bitcoins are gone :( Any ideas / help

Answer (score 1):

> and the merchant said it was possible to either send me less of what i am buying or he can refund my transaction. Since then I received no answer and now i am waiting more than 24h for response.

It sounds to me like the merchant did respond, and is now waiting for you to decide what to do (buy less product, or send the difference).

That's not something we can decide for you.